# STL unordered_map compilation error

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have to implement a class for a directed graph and I need to retrieve the cost associated to an edge as well as inserting/changing the cost in O(1).
Using std::map is fine, the only problem is that it takes O(logn) on average for the specified requirements, so I took a glance at std::unordered_map and tried to use that in my program. The only problem is that I do not quite understand the compilation error.

These are the lines where I try to access the unordered_map (tried [] as well as .insert or .find, still does not work)

```
void DirectedGraph::setValueOfMapEdge(int node1, int node2, int cost) {
        mapEdges.insert({{node1, node2}, cost});
    }

int DirectedGraph::getValueOfMapEdge(int node1, int node2) {
        return mapEdges[make_pair(node1, node2)];
    }
```

This is the error log https://hastebin.com/qawamosuso.vbs

And this is the full code (sorry for the lack of comments)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

class DirectedGraph {
public:
    DirectedGraph() {
        noVertices = 0;
        outboundEdges = inboundEdges = vector<vector<int>>();
    }
    void readFromFile(string fileName);
    void setNoVertices(int vertices);
    void addEdge(int node1, int node2);
    void setValueOfMapEdge(int node1, int node2, int cost);
    int getValueOfMapEdge(int node1, int node2);
    void resizeGraph(int noVertices);
    bool isEdgeBetweenNodes(int node1, int node2);
    int getInDegree(int node);
    int getOutDegree(int node);
    int getNoVertices();
    vector<int> getOutboundNeighboursVector(int node);
    vector<int> getInboundNeighboursVector(int node);
    friend class VertexIterator;

private:
    int noVertices;
    vector<vector<int>> outboundEdges;
    vector<vector<int>> inboundEdges;
    unordered_map<pair<int,int>, int> mapEdges;
    vector<int> inDegree, outDegree;
};

class VertexOutboundIterator {
public:
    VertexOutboundIterator(DirectedGraph *directedGraph, int node) {
        graph = directedGraph;
        vertex = node;
    }
    void first();
    void next();
    bool isDone();
    int currentItem();

private:
    DirectedGraph *graph;
    int vertex;
    int index;
};

void VertexOutboundIterator::first() {
    index = 0;
}

void VertexOutboundIterator::next() {
    ++index;
}

bool VertexOutboundIterator::isDone() {
    return index == graph->getOutboundNeighboursVector(vertex).size();
}

int VertexOutboundIterator::currentItem() {
    return graph->getOutboundNeighboursVector(vertex)[index];
}

class VertexInboundIterator {
public:
    VertexInboundIterator(DirectedGraph *directedGraph, int node) {
        graph = directedGraph;
        vertex = node;
    }

    void first();

    void next();

    bool isDone();

    int currentItem();

private:
    DirectedGraph *graph;
    int vertex;
    int index;
};

void VertexInboundIterator::first() {
    index = 0;
}

void VertexInboundIterator::next() {
    ++index;
}

bool VertexInboundIterator::isDone() {
    return index == graph->getInboundNeighboursVector(vertex).size();
}

int VertexInboundIterator::currentItem() {
    return graph->getInboundNeighboursVector(vertex)[index];
}


vector<int> DirectedGraph::getInboundNeighboursVector(int node) {
    return inboundEdges[node];
}

vector<int> DirectedGraph::getOutboundNeighboursVector(int node) {
    return outboundEdges[node];
}

void DirectedGraph::readFromFile(string fileName) {
    ifstream fin(fileName);
    int noVertices = 0, noEdges = 0;
    fin >> noVertices >> noEdges;
    setNoVertices(noVertices);
    resizeGraph(noVertices);
    int x, y, c;
    for ( int i = 0; i < noEdges; ++i ) {
        fin >> x >> y >> c;
        DirectedGraph::addEdge(x,y);
        DirectedGraph::setValueOfMapEdge(x,y,c);
    }
}

void DirectedGraph::setNoVertices(int vertices) {
    noVertices = vertices;
}

void DirectedGraph::resizeGraph(int noVertices) {
    outboundEdges = inboundEdges = vector<vector<int>>(noVertices);
    inDegree = outDegree = vector<int>(noVertices);
}

void DirectedGraph::addEdge(int node1, int node2) {
    outboundEdges[node1].push_back(node2);
    inboundEdges[node2].push_back(node1);
    inDegree[node2]++;
    outDegree[node1]++;
}

void DirectedGraph::setValueOfMapEdge(int node1, int node2, int cost) {
    mapEdges.insert({{node1, node2}, cost});
}

int DirectedGraph::getValueOfMapEdge(int node1, int node2) {
    return mapEdges[make_pair(node1, node2)];
}

int DirectedGraph::getNoVertices() {
    return noVertices;
};

bool DirectedGraph::isEdgeBetweenNodes(int node1, int node2) {
    for ( const auto node : outboundEdges[node1] )
        if (node == node2)
            return true;
    return false;
}

int DirectedGraph::getInDegree(int node) {
    return inDegree[node];
}

int DirectedGraph::getOutDegree(int node) {
    return outDegree[node];
}

int main() {
    DirectedGraph g = DirectedGraph();
    g.readFromFile("1.txt");
    /*cout << g.isEdgeBetweenNodes(2,0) << '\n';
    cout << g.getOutDegree(2) << '\n';

    VertexOutboundIterator vt = VertexOutboundIterator(&g, 2);
    for ( vt.first(); !vt.isDone(); vt.next() ) {
        cout << vt.currentItem() << '\n';
    }

    VertexInboundIterator ivt = VertexInboundIterator(&g, 3);
    for ( ivt.first(); !ivt.isDone(); ivt.next() )
        cout << ivt.currentItem() << '\n'; */

    cout << g.getValueOfMapEdge(0, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

I am using g++ and the version supports c++11.
Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please read how to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) as a key. For [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) the key needs to be hashed using [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) which have no specialization for `std::pair`.

The [Boost hash library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/hash/reference.htm) have it though, unless you want to make such a specialization yourself.